# Converting a 32bpp image in android (Bitmap instance of type ARGB_8888) to 8bpp, 4bpp and 2bpp

Tags: android, colors, reduce, depth

I need to convert 32bpp images in Android , an instance of Bitmap class with a Bitmap.Config as ARGB_8888.
1. How can I reduce the color depth image to 8bpp and 4bpp?
2. Does android provide any java helper classes to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an external image processing library to do that kind of color quantization. I would prefer use [Leptonica](http://www.leptonica.com/). Its written in C but you can find Android Java bindings in this [project](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/)

Comment: I believe that there is overhead. Jave's solution is easier to use.

Comment: There is no built in android api to transform 8bpp images to 4bpp (it was deprecated). And there is definitely no api to convert to 2bpp. You can only convert form ARGB_888 to RGB_565. For other transformations you have to use an external library.

Comment: I believe that wanted convert from ARGB_8888 to ARGB_4444 and it is possible using copy() method, isn't?

Comment: Yeah but only by using a deprecated method. And then that also leaves the conversion to 2bpp. So there is no way around some overhead(e.g. using external libs) if you want to do color quantization.

Comment: I apologize for coming back very back late on this. But leptonica did the work for me. Thank you  for the help @Renard and others.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`copy()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copy%28android.graphics.Bitmap.Config,%20boolean%29)-method of your bitmap. Here you can specify the resulting color-depth from one of the ones available throught [`Bitmap.Config`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) (16 or 8 bpp, I have seen a few other configurations in various fields in Android but the only ones that seems compatible with the Bitmap are the ones in `Bitmap.Config`).